# Flutter Table Calendar how to display events from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, calendar, table-calendar

I'm making app with Calendar. Im using TableCalendar package. I also use Firebase Firestore in my app. After implementing TableCalendar i want to display events in calendar. Now i want to use FireStore with Table Calendar. How can i make Table Calendar display events from FireStore?

**FireStore**
[image]

**This is how I pull data from FireStore.**

```
Future<List?> getCalendarEvents(String? groupId) async {
List<dynamic>? eventList;

try {
  final _calendarEvent = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("groups")
      .doc(groupId)
      .get();
  eventList = _calendarEvent.data()!["calendarEvents"];
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

return eventList;
```

}

** This is the CalendarHomePage for my app**

```
class _CalendarHomePageState extends State<CalendarHomePage> {
     CalendarController? _calendarController;
Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>? _events;
List<dynamic>? _selectedEvents;
TextEditingController? _eventController;
SharedPreferences? prefs;

Future<List?> _getCalendarEvents() async {
  CurrentUser _currentUser = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context, listen: false);
  List? _calendarEvent = await OurDatabase()
      .getCalendarEvents(_currentUser.getCurrentUser.groupId!);
  print(_calendarEvent);
}  Map<String, dynamic> encodeMap(Map<DateTime, dynamic> map) {
  Map<String, dynamic> newMap = {};
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    newMap[key.toString()] = map[key];
  });
  return newMap;
}

Map<DateTime, dynamic> decodeMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  Map<DateTime, dynamic> newMap = {};
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    newMap[DateTime.parse(key)] = map[key];
  });
  return newMap;
}

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  _calendarController = CalendarController();
  _eventController = TextEditingController();
  _events = {};
  _selectedEvents = [];
  initPrefs();
}

initPrefs() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    _events = Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>.from(
        decodeMap(json.decode(prefs?.getString("events") ?? '{}')));
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('H O M I L Y'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TableCalendar(
            events: _events,
            calendarController: _calendarController,
            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
              formatButtonShowsNext: false,
            ),
            onDaySelected: (date, events, _) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedEvents = events;
              });
            },
            builders: CalendarBuilders(
              selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Text(
                  date.day.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Text(
                  date.day.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ..._selectedEvents!.map(
            (event) => ListTile(
              title: Text(event),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _getCalendarEvents(), child: Text("PRINT"))
        ],
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEventPage()),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through this stackoverflow thread [How to populate Table Calendar with Firestore database snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911856/how-to-populate-table-calendar-with-firestore-database-snapshot)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya yes i checked, but i pull data in list format. I dont know how can i pull data with different way.

Comment: can you check this [How to load events from firebase for a specific user for table calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467362/how-to-load-events-from-firebase-for-a-specific-user-for-tablecalendar)